# Javascript function that finds the next largest palindrome number

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that finds the next largest palindrome for a given positive integer. For example:

```
Input: 2
Output: 3 (every single digit integer is a palindrome)

Input: 180
Output: 181

Input: 17
Output: 22
```

My try

```js
function nextPalindrome(num) {
  let input = num;
  let numToStringArray = input.toString().split('');
  let reversedArray = numToStringArray.reverse();

  if (numToStringArray.length < 2) {
    return Number(numToStringArray) + 1;
  } else {
    while (numToStringArray !== reversedArray) {
      //  numToStringArray = num.toString().split('');
      //  reversedArray = numToStringArray.reverse();
      num += 1;
    }

    return numToStringArray.join('');
  }
}
```

As a beginner, I thought that the numToStringArray would constantly increment by 1 and check for whether the while-statement is true.

Unfortunately it doesn't. I commented out two lines in the while-statement because they seemed somewhat redundant to me. Thanks to everyone reading or even helping me out!

Comment: No code is updating the conditions of your while loop. So if you enter it once, it will loop indefinitely. You need to do something inside of the while loop that might make the condition false the next time through the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because you don't have any code updating the conditions of your while loop. So if you enter it once, it will loop indefinitely. You need to do something inside of the while loop that might make the condition false the next time through the loop, like so:

```js
function getReverse(num) {
  // get the reverse of the number (in positive number form)
  let reversedNum = +Math.abs(num).toString().split("").reverse().join("");
  // keep negative numbers negative
  if (num < 0) { reversedNum *= -1; }
  return reversedNum;
}
function nextPalindrome(num) { 
  // if single digit, simply return the next highest integer
  if (num >= -10 && num < 9) {
     return num+1;
  }
  else {
    while(num !== getReverse(num)) {
      num += 1;
    }
    return num;
  }
}
console.log(nextPalindrome(3));
console.log(nextPalindrome(17));
console.log(nextPalindrome(72));
console.log(nextPalindrome(180));
console.log(nextPalindrome(1005));
console.log(nextPalindrome(-150));
console.log(nextPalindrome(-10));
```

You could also solve this pretty cleanly using recursion, like so:

```js
function getReverse(num) {
  // get the reverse of the number (in positive number form)
  let reversedNum = +Math.abs(num).toString().split("").reverse().join("");
  // keep negative numbers negative
  if (num < 0) { reversedNum *= -1; }
  return reversedNum;
}
function nextPalindrome(num) { 
  // if single digit, simply return the next highest integer
  if (num >= -10 && num < 9) {
     return num+1;
  }
  else if(num === getReverse(num)) {
    return num; 
  }
  else {
    // if not the same, recurse with n + 1
    return nextPalindrome(num + 1)
  }
}
console.log(nextPalindrome(3));
console.log(nextPalindrome(17));
console.log(nextPalindrome(72));
console.log(nextPalindrome(180));
console.log(nextPalindrome(1005));
console.log(nextPalindrome(-150));
console.log(nextPalindrome(-10));
```